# switching to other view breaks app xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, crash, viewswitcher

I'm working on an app, but when I switch from my first view to my second view (game level). The game breaks with:

```
@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
```

and with the alert Threat 1: signal SIGABRT.

I don't know why, by my other views this code work but when I want to switch to this view it breaks down. My switching code is:

```
-(void)collision {

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Redsquare.frame, Invisible.frame)) {
        Level2 *switchtosecondlevelchapter1 = [[Level2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        [self presentModalViewController:switchtosecondlevelchapter1 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me, i'm new to this.
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: i'm sorry I don't know, what you mean by adding breakpoints of logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your nib name for Level2 literally "Level2"... in that case you can provide nil to initWithNibName:
But also add break points and NSLog to debug and see where it is last called... for example you're literal presentModalViewController: code might be fine.... but your CGRectIntersectsRect might be... off.... 
Is everything initialized/non-zero
Look at these different factors and reply as comment

Comment: Yes, it is, i'm going to try it.